# How do you add/remove people dynamically from a list in html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, list

This question has been asked on this forum multiple times. Yet every time I've applied the code and edited the fields to accommodate my code it doesn't seem to work. Essentially I'm trying to develop a list from a form, so once the fields are filled out and you click the add button. The info provided would populate in an ordered list below the form. Here is the following html and javascript code I've got so far. When I click the add button the information that was typed gets showed in the url bar after the original domain name, but it never makes a list.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');

function add(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var people = document.getElementById('people').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name + people + phone));
list.appendChild(entry);

return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Whiskey on Water</title>
<h1>Whiskey on Water: Waiting List</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form id="lineInfo" onsubmit="return add()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Customer Information</legend>
<label for="name">Name*</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
<label for="people">How many people?</label>
<input name="people" id="people" type="number" list="people1" />
<datalist id="people1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="41">41</option>
<option value="42">42</option>
<option value="43">43</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="47">47</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="49">49</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="51">51</option>
<option value="52">52</option>
<option value="53">53</option>
<option value="54">54</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="56">56</option>
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
<option value="61">61</option>
<option value="62">62</option>
<option value="63">63</option>
<option value="64">64</option>
<option value="65">65</option>
<option value="66">66</option>
<option value="67">67</option>
<option value="68">68</option>
<option value="69">69</option>
<option value="70">70</option>
<option value="71">71</option>
<option value="72">72</option>
<option value="73">73</option>
<option value="74">74</option>
<option value="75">75</option>
<option value="76">76</option>
<option value="77">77</option>
<option value="78">78</option>
<option value="79">79</option>
<option value="80">80</option>
<option value="81">81</option>
<option value="82">82</option>
<option value="83">83</option>
<option value="84">84</option>
<option value="85">85</option>
<option value="86">86</option>
<option value="87">87</option>
<option value="88">88</option>
<option value="89">89</option>
<option value="90">90</option>
<option value="91">91</option>
<option value="92">92</option>
<option value="93">93</option>
<option value="94">94</option>
<option value="95">95</option>
<option value="96">96</option>
<option value="97">97</option>
<option value="98">98</option>
<option value="99">99</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</datalist>
<label for="phone">Phone Number*</label>
<input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel"/>
<script src="wow.js"></script>
<button onclick='add ()' type="submit"> Add to List </button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<ol id="list"></ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code works when run as a SO Snippet (see below), so we will need more info about the problem you're having before we can answer your question.

That said, I did notice that your new list item was adding twice, and this is because you are running the `add()` function twice: Once for the onclick handler on the button press, and once as the action of the form upon submit. So, we need to remove one of those... I bet that you'll end up wanting to keep the form, but my working code below removes the form (keeping the onclick on the button) because I bet that your problem is that, although your code works, you are refreshing your page with the form, clearing out the options that have been added to your list. If this sounds right to you then look into passing/fetching the new list items via GET params.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');

function add(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var people = document.getElementById('people').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name + people + phone));
list.appendChild(entry);

return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Whiskey on Water</title>
<h1>Whiskey on Water: Waiting List</h1>
</head>
<body>

<fieldset>
<legend>Customer Information</legend>
<label for="name">Name*</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
<label for="people">How many people?</label>
<input name="people" id="people" type="number" list="people1" />
<datalist id="people1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="41">41</option>
<option value="42">42</option>
<option value="43">43</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="47">47</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="49">49</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="51">51</option>
<option value="52">52</option>
<option value="53">53</option>
<option value="54">54</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="56">56</option>
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
<option value="61">61</option>
<option value="62">62</option>
<option value="63">63</option>
<option value="64">64</option>
<option value="65">65</option>
<option value="66">66</option>
<option value="67">67</option>
<option value="68">68</option>
<option value="69">69</option>
<option value="70">70</option>
<option value="71">71</option>
<option value="72">72</option>
<option value="73">73</option>
<option value="74">74</option>
<option value="75">75</option>
<option value="76">76</option>
<option value="77">77</option>
<option value="78">78</option>
<option value="79">79</option>
<option value="80">80</option>
<option value="81">81</option>
<option value="82">82</option>
<option value="83">83</option>
<option value="84">84</option>
<option value="85">85</option>
<option value="86">86</option>
<option value="87">87</option>
<option value="88">88</option>
<option value="89">89</option>
<option value="90">90</option>
<option value="91">91</option>
<option value="92">92</option>
<option value="93">93</option>
<option value="94">94</option>
<option value="95">95</option>
<option value="96">96</option>
<option value="97">97</option>
<option value="98">98</option>
<option value="99">99</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</datalist>
<label for="phone">Phone Number*</label>
<input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel"/>
<script src="wow.js"></script>
<button onclick='add ()' type="submit"> Add to List </button>
</fieldset>

<ol id="list"></ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've  looked at GET params and how they work but, haven't found them to work at all. I don't know if they aren't being ran or the code is just incorrect, or exactly how to return the information from it. What i did was applied a secondary js to the return of the function add () replacing the false return.

Comment: function addUser(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var people = document.getElementById('people').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode('name' + 'people' + 'phone'));
list.appendChild(entry);
return getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue);}
function getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
} return urlparameter;`

Answer (score 0):

This may help assuming each field has an id:

```js
document.querySelector('#yourButton').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    /* Stop the form from submiting if useful */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* get the values of fields one at a time */
    var field1 = document.querySelector('#input1').value;
    var field2 = document.querySelector('#input2').value;
    ...
    /** prepare new node and insert */
    var newNode = '<ul>'+'<li>'+field1+'</li>'+'<li>'+field2+'</li>'+'</ul>';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(newNode);
});
```